# Display users currently in chat built with node/express/socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, real-time

I'm trying to create a basic chat. Everything is working great except that when a user logs in I'd like to display the users that are currently in the chat. Now what I was planning on doing is just using MongoDB to store an array of active users, adding and removing as necessary. However this seems like it may be an unnecessary amount of overhead. Is there a simple and scalable/memory efficient way to store a list of active users in the chat? I feel like I could just have one giant array of users, but if I ever saw a huge influx in traffic this seems like it would be problematic.

Any help/insight/code/whatever anyone can provide I'd appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io chat app has a nice demo showing presence and chat.

Comment: Thank you, but neither the socket.io demo nor tutorial seem to address the issue I'm trying to solve. Those simply display a count of connected users, I need to store and display a list of connected users by their provided nickname.